# How can I get a v8 function to return a c++ object?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

I'm currently trying to update a C++ library wrapper for Node.js. Currently it uses Nan 1.0 and I need to convert it to use the latest version, Nan 2.0. However, I have run into an interesting problem. I have these two lines:

```
Local<Object> obj;
obj = Nan::Get(result_object, conns[i].from_neuron).As<Object>();
```

When compiled using node-gyp, I receive the error

```
../src/fann-accs.cc:286:59: error: ‘Nan::MaybeLocal<v8::Value>’ has no member named ‘As’
   obj = Nan::Get(result_object, conns[i].from_neuron).As<Object>();
```

How can I get the Nan::Get function to return a c++ object?

Comment: Q: Does this help: https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects

Comment: Yep! Managed to fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed by changing the line from

`obj = Nan::Get(result_object, conns[i].from_neuron).As<Object>();`

to

`obj = result_object->Get(conns[i].from_neuron).As<Object>();`